# Date Conversion From Data Type Date To Five Digit Serial Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a field formatted as date to a serial date using sql server

I have searched the Internet and found no articles on this topic.  I have tried using the DATEADD() function in SQL Server without luck.

```
DATEADD(day, o.filldate, DATEADD(month, o.filldate-1,DATEADD(year, o.filldate-1900, 0))) As serial_filldate
```

An example of a filldate is 3/13/2019

A five digit serial date is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Comment: The `date` and other date/time datatypes has no format, you can't "change" the stored format as it's a binary value. If you need to display it in a certain way you need to do so in your presentation layer.

Comment: What is a "five digit serial date"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? The Excel style "serial date" is the number of days since 01/01/1900, which, conveniently, is day number 0 in SQL Server.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) AS SerialDate
```

Result:

```
+------------+
| SerialDate |
+------------+
|      43549 |
+------------+
```